# How to Animate and Stop Spin Wheel at Value we want

Tags: javascript

I created a spin wheel using javascript and html, all is perfectly work and now I want to add a value where the spin to stop at.

```
    function randomColor(){
        r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 255);
        return {r,g,b}
    }
    function toRad(deg){
        return deg * (Math.PI / 180.0);
    }
    function randomRange(min,max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    function easeOutSine(x) {
        return Math.sin((x * Math.PI) / 2);
    }
    // get percent between 2 number
    function getPercent(input,min,max){
        return (((input - min) * 100) / (max - min))/100
    }


    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
    const width = document.getElementById("canvas").width
    const height = document.getElementById("canvas").height

    const centerX = width/2
    const centerY = height/2
    const radius = width/2

    
    const items = [
          { minDegree: 0, maxDegree: 40, value: 1, name: "chicken" },
          { minDegree: 41, maxDegree: 80, value: 2, name: "neko" },
          { minDegree: 81, maxDegree: 120, value: 3, name: "bird" },
          { minDegree: 121, maxDegree: 160, value: 4, name: "goat" },
          { minDegree: 161, maxDegree: 200, value: 5, name: "sheep" },
          { minDegree: 201, maxDegree: 240, value: 6, name: "duck" },
          { minDegree: 241, maxDegree: 280, value: 7, name: "cow" },
          { minDegree: 281, maxDegree: 320, value: 8, name: "dog" },
          { minDegree: 321, maxDegree: 360, value: 9, name: "cat" },
        ];
    
    console.log(items);

    let currentDeg = 0
    let step = 360/items.length
    let colors = []
    for(let i = 0 ; i < items.length + 1;i++){
        colors.push(randomColor())
    }

    function createWheel(){
        // items = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value.split("\n");
        step = 360/items.length
        colors = []
        for(let i = 0 ; i < items.length + 1;i++){
            colors.push(randomColor())
        }
        draw()
    }
    draw()

    function draw(){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, toRad(0), toRad(360))
        ctx.fillStyle = `rgb(${33},${33},${33})`
        ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
        ctx.fill()

        let startDeg = currentDeg;
        for(let i = 0 ; i < items.length; i++, startDeg += step){
            let rewardName = items[i];
            let endDeg = startDeg + step;
            //console.log(rewardName + " startdegre"  + startDeg + " endDeg" + endDeg);

            color = colors[i]
            let colorStyle = `rgb(${color.r},${color.g},${color.b})`;

            ctx.beginPath();
            rad = toRad(360/step);
            ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - 2, toRad(startDeg), toRad(endDeg));
            let colorStyle2 = `rgb(${color.r - 30},${color.g - 30},${color.b - 30})`;
            ctx.fillStyle = colorStyle2;
            ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
            ctx.fill();

            ctx.beginPath();
            rad = toRad(360/step);
            ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius - 30, toRad(startDeg), toRad(endDeg));
            ctx.fillStyle = colorStyle;
            ctx.lineTo(centerX, centerY);
            ctx.fill();

            // draw text
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(centerX, centerY);
            ctx.rotate(toRad((startDeg + endDeg)/2));
            ctx.textAlign = "center";
            if(color.r > 150 || color.g > 150 || color.b > 150){
                ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
            }
            else{
                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
            }
            ctx.font = 'bold 24px serif';
            ctx.fillText(rewardName, 150, 10);
            ctx.restore();

            // check winner
            if(startDeg%360 < 360 && startDeg%360 > 270  && endDeg % 360 > 0 && endDeg%360 < 90 ){
                document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML = rewardName;
            }
        }
    }
    

    let speed = radiansUntilStop = 0;
    let maxRotation = randomRange(360*3,360*6);
    let pause = false;
    function animate(){
        if(pause){
            return;
        }
        console.log(currentDeg);

        speed = easeOutSine(getPercent(currentDeg ,maxRotation ,0)) * 20
        // speed = getPercent(currentDeg ,maxRotation ,0)
        if(speed < 0.01){
            speed = 0;
            pause = true;
        }
          if( currentDeg >= radiansUntilStop ) {
            // stop spinning the wheel
            currentDeg = radiansUntilStop;
            speed = 0;
             pause = true;
          }
        
        currentDeg += speed;
        draw()
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    
    function spin(){
        if(speed != 0){
            return
        }
        currentDeg = 0
        maxRotation = randomRange(360*3,360*6)
        console.log(maxRotation);
        radiansUntilStop = 41;
        pause = false
        window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
```

I set a value radiansUntilStop to stop the spin at "neko" yes its stop at it, but the spin not animate (spin at random times then stop) only stop without animation
here is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/wsmcf8ub/

I try to remove the code

```
      if( currentDeg >= radiansUntilStop ) {
        // stop spinning the wheel
        currentDeg = radiansUntilStop;
        speed = 0;
         pause = true;
      }
```

then it animate the spin but will stop at random value

https://jsfiddle.net/7b61p4az/

What I want is to animate it then stop at value we set, any ways to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add variable to hold the array you have.

```
let itemArr = {}
```

Then add the value to the string

```
itemArr[items[i]] = 
                {
                "startDeg": startDeg,
                "endDeg" : endDeg
                }
```

When you click on spin button then set a stop value

```
maxRotation = (360 * 6) - itemArr['cat'].endDeg + 10
```

So that your spinner can stop at Cat.

Help me to upvote and mark this as answer if this was your fix

Comment: Thanks you saved my day by this maxRotation = (360 * 6) - itemArr['cat'].endDeg + 10